# How to navigate to Half Fragment ? (Navigation Architecture Component)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying Navigation architecture Component in My app.
Earlier i Used Fragment Transaction's to achieve the below feature.
Basically i want to navigate from.

**FragmentA->FragmentB**
*(custom fragment partially transparent and half of screen size)*

If i am using Navigation component and try

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_FragmentA_to_FragmentB)
```

Then the result is the FragmentA is replaced by FragmentB and the background fragment is not visible.

*I want to know of a solution if it's allowed by Navigation Architecture Component.*

*P.S: I have heard about nested Navigation Host,But is it good to use from inside Fragment.*

**Update:**

The FragmentB will have action's for further transaction's and 
example:

**FragmentA->FragmentB->FragmentC** *(custom fragment partially transparent and half of screen size)*

And Fragment C should replace FragmentB when user press back button and backStack should be maintained for all the fragment transactions.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TLDR:I used nested graphs for achieving the requirement.*

Hello, thanks for help but navigating in BottomSheet is achieved by me using below procedure.

- **MainActivity**

  - NavHost(**FragXYZ->FragA**)

    - (**Inside Fragment A**)BottomSheetDialogFragment.show() to display the bottomSheetMenu

      - (**Inside Fragment B**) BottomSheetDialog**Child**Fragment(start child Fragment of BottomSheetDialogFragment using Fragment 
        Transaction) extends NavHostFragment

Demo:[GitHub](https://github.com/andor201995/NavigationDemo)

Answer (score 2):

You can use BottomSheetDialogFragment to get the desired result.

More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: Have you tried it using Navigation architecture Component ??
and give's the above result

Comment: @ANMOLSRIVASTAVA haven't tried with the Navigation Architecture but BottomSheet can easily give you that result.

Comment: You should just use a bottom sheet (I say, as the person who wrote the Navigation Architecture Component).

Comment: i Know how to create bottomSheet but Navigation Architecture replace's the below fragment and the fragment below is not visible.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Navigation at all for dialogs or bottom sheet dialogs. Just use `show()` to show the bottom sheet.

Comment: @ianhanniballake what i am trying to achieve is a Bottom menu where it will show different fragment in bottomSheet based on user input so when user press back button it should not remove the bottom Dialog but go to the last fragment in bottom menu.So need a backStack for bottomMenu.So, i planned to use navigation component for bottom menu which will be having a hierarchy of fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake what about when you want to close the bottom sheet when the user presses 'back'?

Comment: @papageorgiouk - dialogs already handle the system back button

Comment: @ianhanniballake and when I want to do it manually? Like closing an expanded appbar for example?