# Navigation Component : Show Fragment A partially while moved to Fragment B

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Lets assume that while implementing Navigation component, **Fragment A** moved to a destination **Fragment B** upon some action. Fragment B is a full screen fragment with margins on top, bottom, left & right side (Lets assume 50 dp on each side).

What are the options here in order to show Fragment A behind Fragment B while using navigation graph. Using the transparent background image or image with 50 % opacity for Fragment B doesn't work (It covers up all the screen area with default background color i.e. White and Fragment A is completely hidden)

I want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417322/how-to-navigate-to-half-fragment-navigation-architecture-component) but at the centre of screen and not with bottom sheet where user can drag and hide the view.

Comment: You want to create a `DialogFragment` not a fragment to which you want to navigate

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Yes, but even if Fragment B extends from DialogFragment class, same problem exists. Fragment A hides due to the white background.

Comment: You need to create a view which has a transparent background and a view inside it which doesn't take the entire screen with a white background